# How to get url which starts with using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How to get full url which starts url with  `http://sin1.g.adnxs.com`

here is my code

```
<div id="testingurl">
    <div class="ads98E6LYS20621080">

<!--  we are getting this  script  dynamically -->
 <iframe src="http://testing.com">

if the anchor link start with http://sin1.g.adnxs.com then alert

</iframe>
<!--  we are getting this  script  dynamically -->
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: From where, you are taking url as input?

Answer (score 0):

Use this logic

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  if (window.location.href.startsWith('http://sin1.g.adnxs.com')){
      alert('Your message') ;
   }
});
```

Comment: I assume you have not looked properly for question asked...It clearly says `start with` not is exactly same as `http://sin1.g.adnxs.com`

Comment: Incorrect ! You can't use `=` to check your IF case.

Comment: Now i think it will make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking something like this:

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("http://www.sin1.g.adnxs.com") > -1) {
    alert(window.location.href);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(window.location.origin == 'http://sin1.g.adnxs.com'){
   alert('some alert');
}
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are discouraged, because they don't teach the solution.

Answer (score 0):

As other suggested, you can use window.location.origin in order to get that url
Example:

```
if(window.location.origin === 'http://sin1.g.adnxs.com'){
   alert('alert');
}
```

Generally you can use window.location for:

```
window.location.href returns the href (URL) of the current page
window.location.hostname returns the domain name of the web host
window.location.pathname returns the path and filename of current page
window.location.protocol returns the web protocol used (http:// or https://)
window.location.assign loads a new document
```

More info can be found here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location

**EDIT:**

Please have a look at the following example.

In case you have two web pages, parent.html and content.html and content.html is
displayed within parent.html using an `iframe`.

If you want check the URL of parent.html within content.html you can use the following script:

-------------------------- parent.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Demo</title>
        <style>

        </style>
        <script>
        window.name = 'parent';
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
PARENT

<iframe src="content.html" width="200" height="200"></iframe>


</body>
</html>
```

-------------------------- content.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo</title>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: red;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        app = {
            start: function () {
                window.name = 'content';
                var parent = window.parent;
                console.log(parent.name);
                if (parent.location.origin === 'http://sin1.g.adnxs.com') {
                    alert('alert');
                }
            }
        };

    </script>
</head>
<body onload="app.start();">

    CONTENT
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is your URL in project window?

Comment: @deb new edit with a possible solution to your problem, I hope it helps. Please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: let me check with your source

Comment: i updated question please check i don't know exactly till now today we updated question this is the exact question sorry for not  writing exact question

Comment: not sure if I understand your last edit. You could try to use onload on the iframe in orde <iframe id="ifrm" src="xxxx.html" onload="doSomething()"></iframe>

Comment: i understand i kept onload also but iframe also getting dynamically i updated question please see